# How to serialize this program and deserialize it

Tags: java, serialization, output, deserialization

Can i know how to serialize and deserialize this program , im not able to figure it out , should i use arrays to store the content that is being printed out..?

It has two classes in two seperate calss files.
one is player and the other is SnakeAndladder1

```
Player class
------------

package coll.org;

public class Player {

private String name;
private int score;

Player(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getScore() {
    return score;
}
public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}   

}


SnakeAndladder1 class
---------------------


package coll.org;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SnakeAndladder1 {
ArrayList<String> name1=new ArrayList<String>(); //an array to store players names

public int throwdice() //to calculate the dice value
{
    return (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
}

public int ladder(int curscore)
{
    Hashtable<Integer,Integer> ld = new Hashtable<Integer,Integer>();

    //Map<Integer,Integer> ldmap = new Map<Integer,Integer>();
    ld.put(15,30);
    ld.put(45,71);
    ld.put(25,62);
    ld.put(81,91);
    ld.put(9,39);
    while(curscore!=15 || curscore!=45 || curscore!=25 || curscore!=81 || curscore!=9)
    { return curscore;}
    int v=ld.get(15);
    return v;

}
public int snake(int curscore)
{
    Hashtable<Integer,Integer> ld = new Hashtable<Integer,Integer>();
    ld.put(29,11);
    ld.put(81,48);
    ld.put(30,6);
    ld.put(92,71);
    ld.put(58,19);
    while(curscore!=29 || curscore!=81 || curscore!=30 || curscore!=92 || curscore!=58 )
    {return curscore;}
    int v=ld.get(curscore);
    return v;
}


public boolean Game (Player p){
    //int score=0;
    //String name;
    int v=0;
    //name=name1.toString();
        System.out.println("Click y to roll dice");
        Scanner in2=new Scanner(System.in);
        String yes=in2.nextLine();
        if(yes.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            v=throwdice();
            System.out.println("dice value:"+v);
        }
        p.setScore(p.getScore()+v);
        if(p.getScore()==100)
        {
            System.out.println("User:"+p.getName()+"got"+v+".Winner!!!");
            return false;
        }
        if (p.getScore()>100)
        {
            p.setScore(p.getScore()-v);
            System.out.println("Current score of"+p.getName()+"is"+p.getScore());
            return true;
        }

        int s1=ladder(p.getScore());
        if(s1==p.getScore())
        {
            p.setScore(snake(p.getScore()));
            System.out.println("Current score of"+p.getName()+"is"+p.getScore());
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            p.setScore(s1);
            System.out.println("Current score of"+p.getName()+"is"+p.getScore());
            return true;
        }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int l=0;
//boolean flag=true;
System.out.println("Enter the number of players:");
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter Players names in order:");
ArrayList<Player> p1=new ArrayList<Player>(); //an array to store players names
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    Scanner in1=new Scanner(System.in);
    String name2=in1.nextLine();
    Player p = new Player(name2);
    p1.add(p);
    //name1.add(name2);
}
//Snakeandladder1[] players = new Snakeandladder1[n];
//ArrayList<Snakeandladder1> player=new ArrayList<Snakeandladder1>();
//for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    //player.add(new Snakeandladder1());
//  SnakeAndladder1 players[];
//  players = new SnakeAndladder1[n];
SnakeAndladder1 sk = new SnakeAndladder1();
while(true)
{
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        Player p3=p1.get(i);
        boolean flag = sk.Game(p3);
        if (flag == false)
        {System.exit(0);}
    }
  }
}
}
```

This program is allows any number of players and ask for the user to enter y to roll dice, i have got the output but i am not able to serialize  it. Is there a way to take the output after the execution of the program is complete and serialize it ??

Answer (score 0):

A neat library exists to serialize objects into XML files (and of course deserialize them after). It's extremely simple to use and very effective.

http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html

Comment: You mean the class variables can change? The library basically takes the member variables and store them as fields for the XML, with their value. Each class will have their structure and you'll be able to reconstruct the whole object after. Please precise what you mean by "the fields change".

Comment: yes the class variables change..the score variable changes for every iterarion.

Comment: Okay, then I would suggest to still use the library, but instead of using member variables like you did, using a member hash-map which will map your needed variables to string keys. Once you deserialize, you will get a Hash-map with certain key-values, so in your getter and setter you can check if the value is in the hash-map, if not add one with a default value (since it's impossible after all to get a value if you didn't have a similar variable at the time of serialization). Heres the hash-map [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)